# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on macbook 12 retina 2015

Tags: wireless, keyboard, touchpad, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook 12' retina 2015. I have been able to install it but the keyboard, the touchpad and WiFi actually does not work... I am trying to find informations but I have only found it for installing on Macbook pro and Air and all the solutions have failed... Any idea?

Thanks to everyone who can help me!!

Answer (score 4):

people have been trying to find a solution since the MacBook 12' was released last year, but from my searches no one seems to have solved the problem yet.

The link below gives an idea of where things are at the moment:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99891

Hope this helps!!!